# How to skip n rows for order by clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have a dataset. The first 2 rows should be ignored and ordering (by name column) should start from the 3rd row. And it should be done through a query only.

```
aaa g   900
zzz g   900  -- the first 2 rows should be fixed 
bb  g   900  -- ordering should start from here 
yy  g   900
rrr g   900
fff g   900
```

Desired output:

```
    aaa g   900
    zzz g   900  
    bb  g   900  
    ff  g   900
    rrr g   900
    yy  g   900
```

Comment: You can "skip" rows using the `OFFSET` clause, however, I see no `ORDER BY` clause that would retain the order of your data in the order it is in.

Comment: How can you define your `first 2 rows` without an order by?

Comment: you can use a cte
;with a as (select row_number() r, col1, col2 from t) select * from t where r > 2 order by col1

Answer (score 3):

You can use `case` logic in the `order by`:

```
order by (case when col1 = 'aaa' then 1
               when col1 = 'zzz' then 2
               else 3
          end),
         col1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from table_name
except 
select top 2 *
from table_name
order by column_name
```